# Escaping the URL in the angularjs

Tags: angularjs

`<a ng-href="#/abc/{{ value }}/xyz">{{ value }}</a>`

In the above angular snippet, how to handle, when the `value` has `/` in it ? As it will be considered as a different url.

Comment: Perhaps this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2598) might help?

Comment: Create a filter to clean it. Or create url friendly slugs that convert `foo/bar` to `foo-bar`

Comment: Thanks Eric, I was not aware of that issue.

Comment: It's a valid suggestion charlietfl, but I cannot do that on the current code, it has some limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the value twice with **encodeURIComponent** which worked for me, you can try as shown below. 
And if you needs to get the value decode back then use **decodeURIComponent** twice as like encode function to do the revert.

Template:

```
<a ng-href="#/abc/{{ encodeTwice(value) }}/xyz">{{ value }}</a>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.encodeTwice=function(value){
   return encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(value));
}
```